# hack for "mongo db connection refused due to blocked port errno 10061"

Tags: mongodb, tcp, mlab

I m trying connect to my db in Mongolab:

```
>> mongo ds123456.mongolab.com
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.1
connecting to: ds123456.mongolab.com/test
2014-12-16T14:13:41.738+0100 warning: Failed to connect to 54.74.247.101:27017, reason: errno:10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
2014-12-16T14:13:41.741+0100 Error: couldn't connect to server ds123456.mongolab.com:27017 (54.74.247.101), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:148
exception: connect failed
```

I assume [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21153318/mongodb-could-not-connect-to-server) answers the first problem of access being blocked on this port.

The obvious solution is to contact the network admin. But I wonder if there is an alternative?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have an open port you could use it by changing the port used by mongod.

Comment: i have a simple account on mongolab, canT change the port :/

Comment: try: `mongo <host>:<port>/<db> -u <user> -p <password>` . Those parameters should have been provided for you somehow :)

Comment: thanks but it s practically the same thing, afaik. and it doesnT work either.

Comment: I believe this belongs on ServerFault or dba. Anyway, to diagnose whether it's truly an *outbound* firewall rule (I doubt it), run a `netcat -l -p 27017` on some remote machine and try to connect from it using `netcat` or `telnet`. Otherwise, for local development, maybe it's easier to use a local instance of MongoDB and only use mongolab from the deployed live instance?